# Pre-processing data in R: filtering and replacing using wildcards

Tags: r, wildcard, na

Good day!

I have a dataset in which I have values like `"Invalid"`, `"Invalid(N/A)"`, `"Invalid(1.23456)"`, lots of them in different columns and they are different from file to file.

Goal is to make script file to process different CSVs.

I tried `read.csv` and `read_csv`, but faced errors with data types or no errors, but no action either.

All columns are `col_character` except one - `col_double`.

Tried this:

```
is.na(df) <- startsWith(as.character(df, "Inval")
```

no luck

Tried this:

```
is.na(df) <- startsWith(df, "Inval")
```

no luck, some error about non char object

Tried this:

```
    df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), .fns = ~str_replace(., "invalid", NA_character_)))
```

no luck

And other google stuff - no luck, again, errors with data types or no errors, but no action either.

So R is incapable of simple find and replace in data frame, huh?

[data frame exampl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbQfg.png)

Output of `dput(dtype_Result[1:20, 1:4])`

```
structure(list(Location = c("1(1,A1)", "2(1,B1)", "3(1,C1)", 
"4(1,D1)", "5(1,E1)", "6(1,F1)", "7(1,G1)", "8(1,H1)", "9(1,A2)", 
"10(1,B2)", "11(1,C2)", "12(1,D2)", "13(1,E2)", "14(1,F2)", "15(1,G2)", 
"16(1,H2)", "17(1,A3)", "18(1,B3)", "19(1,C3)", "20(1,D3)"), 
    Sample = c("Background0", "Background0", "Standard1", "Standard1", 
    "Standard2", "Standard2", "Standard3", "Standard3", "Standard4", 
    "Standard4", "Standard5", "Standard5", "Standard6", "Standard6", 
    "Control1", "Control1", "Control2", "Control2", "Unknown1", 
    "Unknown1"), EGF = c(NA, NA, "6.71743640129069", "2.66183193679533", 
    "16.1289784536322", "16.1289784536322", "78.2706654825781", 
    "78.6376213069722", "382.004087907716", "447.193928257862", 
    "Invalid(N/A)", "1920.90297258996", "7574.57784103579", "29864.0308009592", 
    "167.830723655146", "109.746615928611", "868.821939675054", 
    "971.158518683179", "9.59119569511596", "4.95543581398464"
    ), `FGF-2` = c(NA, NA, "25.5436745776637", NA, "44.3280630362038", 
    NA, "91.991708192168", "81.9459159768959", "363.563899234418", 
    "425.754478700876", "Invalid(2002.97340881547)", "2027.71958119836", 
    "9159.40221389147", "11138.8722428849", "215.58494072476", 
    "70.9775438699825", "759.798876479002", "830.582605561901", 
    "58.7007261370257", "70.9775438699825")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Sorry, but even dput(head(df, 20)) is a 2-3 scrolling screen length, is it needed?

Comment: In that case, subset also the columns, `head` selects the first rows. It could be `dput(df[1:20, 1:4])` to select the first 20 rows and the first 4 columns.

Comment: @RuiBarradas done

Comment: Thanks for the data. I have tested my solution below with it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the use of `startsWith`. The following `grepl` solution is simpler and works.

```
is.na(df) <- sapply(df, function(x) grepl("^Invalid", x))
```

Comment: Or can be `is.na(df) <- `dim<-`(grepl("^Invalid", as.matrix(df)), dim(df))`

Comment: @akrun, thx, but i cannot understand this construction :)

Comment: @eliz_z `grep/grepl` expects a vector, converting to matrix does that (as matrix is a vector with dim attributes.  The output from grep is now a logical vector, which we create the dimenssion with `dim<-` before doing the `<-` to NA

Comment: @akrun error: unexpected ',' in "is.na(dtype_Result2) <- dim <- (grepl("^Invalid", as.matrix(dtype_Result2)),"

Comment: @eliz_z you need backquotes around `dim<-`

Comment: @akrun error: unexpected ',' in "is.na(dtype_Result2) <- `dim` <- (grepl("^Invalid", as.matrix(dtype_Result2)),"

Comment: @eliz_z it is not giving me error  though

Comment: @akrun OR error in `dim <-`(grepl("^Invalid", as.matrix(dtype_Result2)), dim(dtype_Result2)) :
  cannot find function "dim <-"

Comment: @eliz_z As I said earlier, there would be without spaces i.e. `is.na(df) <- "dim<-"(grepl("^Invalid", as.matrix(df)), dim(df))` either backquote or quote would work

Comment: where `df <- structure(list(col1 = c("Invalid", "4", "5"), col2 = c("7", "9", 
"Invalid")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: It work!! Thank you. I think R is waaay complicated in details.

Answer (score 0):

The `str_replace` function will attempt to edit the content of a character string, inserting a partial replacement, rather than replacing it entirely. Also, the `across` function is targeting all of the columns including the numeric id. The following code works, building on the tidyverse example you provided.

To fix it, use `where` to identify the columns of interest, then use `if_else` to overwrite the data with NA values when there is a partial string match, using `str_detect` to spot the target text.

Example data

```
library(tiyverse)

df <- tibble(
    id = 1:3,
    x = c("a", "invalid", "c"),
    y = c("d", "e", "Invalid/NA")
)

df

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id x       y         
  <int> <chr>   <chr>     
1     1 a       d         
2     2 invalid e         
3     3 c       Invalid/NA
```

Solution

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(
       across(where(is.character), 
       .fns = ~if_else(str_detect(tolower(.x), "invalid"), NA_character_, .x))
    )

print(df)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id x     y    
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     d    
2     2 NA    e    
3     3 c     NA
```

Comment: Please describe the problem a bit more, The example given worked on my machine

Comment: got, for example, 2 random values "Invalid(N/A)" "Invalid(2002.97340881547)" and it didnt change, even there is no errors

Comment: '
> dtype_Result2 %>% 
+ 
+   mutate(
+     across(where(is.character), 
+            .fns = ~if_else(str_detect(tolower(.x), "invalid"), NA_character_, .x))
+   )
# A tibble: 90 x 43
   Location Sample  EGF '

Comment: strange, i repeat exact your code and after  df %>% mutate it shows exact your result, but if hit df again, then it shows old values. So df1 <- df %>%, then df1 got correct values.

Comment: Right, my example code doesn't assign the output anywhere, which leaves the input data frame unchanged.  I'll update the the code to clarify